# Setting an element of an array equal to an entire array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am creating a deck of bingo cards. The deck knows the amount of cards in the deck, the size of the cards, and the max number to appear on the card.

I want to create n arrays (cards) of unique random integers and then add each of these arrays to each element of another array (the deck). So, an array of arrays.

Ex.

```
card1 = {1, 2, 5};
card2 = {3, 7, 2};
deck = {card1, card2};
```

Here is my code so far:

```
Deck::Deck(int cardSize, int cardCount, int numberMax){
    int randInt;
    int size = cardSize * cardSize;
    int deckArr[cardCount];
    for(int t = 0; t < cardCount; t++){
        int arr[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            randInt = computeRandInt(numberMax, cardSize);
            if(arr[i] == 0) arr[i] = randInt;
            else if (randInt != arr[i-1]) arr[i] = randInt;
        }
        deckArr[t] = arr;
    }
}
```

I get the error invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’. How do I declare my deck array to store these card arrays?

Comment: `int deckArr[cardCount]` -- `int arr[size];` -- This is not valid C++.  An array in C++ must be declared using a constant to denote the number of entries, not a variable.  Use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, you can deal with arrays of arrays by means of nested vectors, e.g. a `vector<vector<int>>` for your `deckArr`. Note that `deckArr` should actually be a member of `Deck` (and not a local variable); Just slightly adapted your code to show the idea of nested vectors:

```
Deck::Deck(int cardSize, int cardCount, int numberMax){
    int randInt;
    int size = cardSize * cardSize;
    vector<vector<int>> deckArr(cardCount);
    for(int t = 0; t < cardCount; t++){
        vector<int> arr(size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            randInt = computeRandInt(numberMax, cardSize);
            if(arr[i] == 0) arr[i] = randInt;
            else if (randInt != arr[i-1]) arr[i] = randInt;
        }
        deckArr.push_back(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So how would I access the deck vector in another print function to print out each card?